# Emailing attachments using SMTP server

Tags: php, email

I am a little confused about how it works sending emails using an external SMTP server with attachments.

Let's say I have a contact form on my website which allows attachments uploads, and I use an external SMTP server, such as Amazon SES or Gmail.

Does the file need to be first uploaded to my server, and then I point the email attachment to that filepath, or does it get converted to base64 and sent within the body of the SMTP?

***Question:*** Does the file get sent directly or does it first need to be uploaded to my server?

Comment: whenever you use a file upload and post it to the server it will get uploaded into a temp directory, generally `/var/tmp` on unix based systems.  I would suggest using a mail framework for SMTP mail on Unix, like PHPMailer, as this does a pretty good job of handling the socket connection, and supports sending attachments. The attachment can be sent directly from the tmp directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The browser has to make an HTTP request to the HTTP server with the file embedded in it.
2. The HTTP server reads the request and hands it over to PHP.
3. PHP reads the request and extracts the file from it (due to the way PHP is implemented, this will involve storing it as a temp file that will be deleted after the PHP program finishes running)
4. Your PHP program needs to read the data from the file and embed it in the email as an attachment
5. The resulting email message (including the attachment) is passed over SMTP

There is no need to *store* the file on the server.

Comment: Ok so it needs to be moved to my server but only temporarily. Super, thank you.